# Merging two lists, one with duplicate elements and one with integers, into dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge, addition

So I have two lists which have been created by grabbing JSON data based on a few parameters, for example:

```
list_1 = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'pink')
list_2 = [0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 1.5]
```

In the JSON data, the key `'red'` has value `0.1` in one nested array and `0.5` in another. The lists are in order so `list_1[0]` corresponds to `list_2[0]` and `list_1[1]` to `list_2[1]` etc...

My aim is to end up with a dictionary where there are unique elements from `list_1` and *combined* values from `list_2`. For example:

`dict_1 = {'red': 0.6, 'green': 0.1, 'blue': 1.3, 'yellow': 0.4, 'pink': 1.5}`

I've been messing around with `zip`, `zip_longest`, `map` but I've found that these won't work. I've reached the point where I'm going back to the drawing board in regards to how I get the JSON data but if someone has a neat snippet of code that would be awesome.

Comment: Basically same idea as in dupe, just zipping the pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to generate pairs and iterate over them:

```
list_1 = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'pink']
list_2 = [0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 1.5]

res = {}
for key, value in zip(list_1, list_2):
    if key in res:
        res[key] += value
    else:
        res[key] = value
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the value for red will be 0.5 and not 0.6 as it's overwritten due to dictionaries not allowing multiple keys.

Comment: @T.BJ, check post edits

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `defaultdict` for this:

```
list_1 = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'pink']
list_2 = [0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 1.5]

from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(float)

for k, v in zip(list_1, list_2):
    res[k] += v
```

Comment: Even if it works, it's correct to pass `float` as default type.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Missed that, thanks.